# Trying to configure a wifi bssid on netplan (need some examplesthat works)

Tags: wireless, netplan

I'm trying to force a wifi connection thru a specific 5GHz network using the bssid on netplan configuration but it always report an error when I ran *netplan apply* command.

Here is my current configuration that fails:

```
wlan0:
  dhcp4: true
  dhcp6: false
  link-local: []
  access-points:
    "wifissid":
      password: "wifipassword"
    bssid: "3c:28:6d:95:76:00"
```

The error is the following:

```
sudo netplan apply
/etc/netplan/30-wlan0.yaml:10:16: Error in network definition: expected mapping (check indentation)
        bssid: "3c:28:6d:95:76:00"
               ^
```

Tried many different combinations but it always fail.
Could you help me providing an example that works?

Thank you in advance.
Ederson Santos

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Added the information requested to the post.

Comment: Indent bssid so that it matches the password line above. Both are sub-items of the same access point.

Comment: Yes, It's the MAC address assigned to SSID called Basic Service Set Identification (BSSID). The problem is that the documentation from *https://netplan.io/reference/* is not clear how can we configure it. I know that it's a yaml, but with my experience with yaml configuration was not sufficient to set it correctly.

Comment: @user535733, I tried all the combinations without success. Do you have any example how it could be?

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing tabs and spaces on your indentation to match the 'password' line. That's a common stumble.

Comment: Sure. Just reviewed that point but it still failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you have the `bssid` indented such that it is listed directly under the `access-points` mapping as if it were an SSID.  It must be indented so that it's under the SSID it's associated with (in the above example, indented so that it's under `wifissid`).

Answer (score 0):

"You can find many templates in /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/" according to the posting I just read in the link below. It is near the bottom where they give the address to the netplan.io site.

[How to configure wpa_supplicant in Ubuntu server 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242256/how-to-configure-wpa-supplicant-in-ubuntu-server-20-04)