# Why does Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi fail to connect to Wi-Fi on first boot?

Tags: networking, 20.04, raspberrypi, netplan

The bottom of the network setup page of the ["How to install Ubuntu Server on your Raspberry Pi" tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#3-wifi-or-ethernet) says,

> Note: During the first boot, your Raspberry Pi will try to connect to this network. It will fail the first time around. Simply reboot `sudo reboot` and it will work.

Why does it fail the first time? On the first boot is also when `cloud-init` runs, and if it cannot connect to the network, many `cloud-init` stages (like installing packages) will fail.

Instead of creating `network-config` on the boot partition, is there another file I could create that would properly configure the network on first boot?

Comment: There is discussion of this [on the Discourse post that generates that tutorial](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-on-your-raspberry-pi/14660/48) but the solutions are a little cargo-culty and I'm trying to figure out which ones are actually true.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could try a mount of the sd card then edit of the files needed to see if it will work on first boot as described in link below. Or simplely plug in the network cable if it has the port and have it work for certain for that part of its setup, then switch to wireless after it is setup and configured for it.

[How to configure wpa_supplicant in Ubuntu server 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242256/how-to-configure-wpa-supplicant-in-ubuntu-server-20-04)