# Cannot get internet working with Ubuntu Server on my lpatop

Tags: networking, drivers, server, usb

I have an HP 430 G1 laptop. It originally had Windows on it. I installed Ubuntu Desktop on it.
I am able to connect to wifi. No Problem here. Ethernet port is not working.

I wanted to install ubuntu server on it and wanted to tinker around. But I cant get the wifi to work on Ubuntu server.

I have done following

1. [Configure netplan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242256/how-to-configure-wpa-supplicant-in-ubuntu-server-20-04)
2. This one does not work because wlan0 i enter in config does not exist.
3. I did `iw dev` to get devices, but it comes up empty
4. Then I found these two links install Broadcom drivers [Link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) and [Link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730799/installing-firmware-b43-installer-offline/730813#730813)
5. for above links to work I have to get it on USB and put it on my sever machine.
6. But USB drive shows `special device /dev/sdb1/ does not exist (a path prefix is not a directory)`
7. seems like I am in dead lock situation

I have installed multiple different OS on this laptop in past 2 days.
Proxmox Backup Server - USB works here, I can mount and get it data from it on the machine but wifi absolutely does not work here. Please suggest some way to get on the internet.

Edit1: `ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64` and `ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64` these are the ISO's I have

Comment: You didn't provide any release details; which maybe the difference between your desktop & server system.  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop for example defaults to the HWE kernel stack; however Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server defaults to GA kernel stack... Adding the other stack is the obvious fix if it was that release; but you gave no release specifics, or kernel stack details..  (ISO used for install dictates the kernel stack installed for some releases...)   You tagged *drivers* which are technically called *kernel modules*; but didn't give the release/kernel details...

Comment: I dont' actually know about stack, but here is what I have, `ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64` and `ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64`. How would I get the stack you are taking about in my server iso?

Comment: You had different products, with different defaults.  The server (ISO) install defaults to GA stack where as the desktop (ISO) you had defaulted to a different HWE stack which is likely why you had different responses to both. You can have both stacks installed (*on most boxes; some closed-source video drivers do prevent this though*) to make both work the same - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  (the server ISO/install lets you select the stack at install time; desktop ISO/install does not).   See "*Server: Installing the HWE stack is simple*" in provided doc.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand the difference sort of. But the commands that are given in above documents require I already have ubuntu installed. I may have to install Desktop first and run this command `ubuntu-drivers list-oem` . I am not sure if the `apt install` command would work without internet connection.